# How to get battery status?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I get the battery status on an iPhone?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batLeft = [myDevice batteryLevel];
int i=[myDevice batteryState];

int batinfo=(batLeft*100);

NSLog(@"Battry Level is :%d and Battery Status is :%d",batinfo,i);

switch (i)
{
    case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged:
    {
        [BCStatus setText:NSLocalizedString(@"UnpluggedKey", @"")];
        break;
    }
    case UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging:
    {
        [BCStatus setText:NSLocalizedString(@"ChargingKey", @"")];
        break;
    }
    case UIDeviceBatteryStateFull:
    {
        [BCStatus setText:NSLocalizedString(@"FullKey", @"")];
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        [BCStatus setText:NSLocalizedString(@"UnknownKey", @"")];
        break;
    }
}
```

BCStatus is uilabel.

Comment: worth noting that the associated notifications `UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification` and `UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification` do not get sent if your app is executing in background

Comment: what is battery status here?

Comment: @Codecracker batteryLevel is float value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 and batteryState is some kind of code which states device is charged, in charging, etc.

Comment: worth noting that 'setBatteryMonitoringEnabled' method isn't thread safe, as mentioned in https://github.com/jszumski/uidevice-threading-crash, http://openradar.appspot.com/13941890, https://twitter.com/cheesemaker/status/517373206748205056.

Answer (score 3):

Iphone SDK 3.0 beta supports this.

Comment: ...and then again, it might have been announced by Apple in a public forum.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are very good, but they are all in Obj-C, I have used these with other examples to do the same task on `MonoTouch`, so I am putting my code here in case anybody needs it:

```
try
{
    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryMonitoringEnabled = true;
    _Battery.Level = (int)(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryLevel * IOSBatteryLevelScalingFactor);
    _Battery.State = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryState;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ExceptionHandler.HandleException(e, "BatteryState.Update");
    throw new BatteryUpdateException();
}
finally
{
    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.BatteryMonitoringEnabled = false;
}
```

I also have a full post on my blog to give all the details in [here](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/reading-battery-level-and-status-in-ios-using-monotouch/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used for my string as a quick utility method, note that you have to enable battery monitoring to get a value, and then if you don't want to get the notifications (obviously some efficiency to be gained there, since they give you the ability to turn it off) then you should turn it off again after (like I do in this function):

```
NSString *statusString(void)
{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSString *batteryStateString = nil;
    switch(device.batteryState)
    {
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged: batteryStateString = @"Unplugged"; break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging: batteryStateString = @"Charging"; break;
        case UIDeviceBatteryStateFull: batteryStateString = @"Full"; break;
        default: batteryStateString = @"Unknown"; break;
    }

    [device setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    NSString *statusString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Battery Level - %d%%, Battery State - %@",
                              (int)round(device.batteryLevel * 100), batteryStateString];
    [device setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:NO];
    return statusString;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Now that the 3.1 SDK is released look for the Getting the Device Battery State section in UIDevice's documentation. It is abunch of battery* properties.