# How to read battery case status from the iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get battery status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330461/how-to-get-battery-status)

I am implementing one iPhone application in which i want to read battery status of the iPhone by programming. I dont know is it possible or not. Please give me advice for that.

Answer (score 4):

To read battery level and status you just have to:

```
float battLvl = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]; // range is from 0.0 to 1.0
UIDeviceBatteryState battState = [UIDevice currentDevice] batteryStatus];
```

To monitor battery level and status you can do the following:

```
// enable monitoring and add observers with selector
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
device.batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification" object:device];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification" object:device];

// Your notification handler
- (void)batteryChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    NSLog(@"state: %i | charge: %f", device.batteryState, device.batteryLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following lines of code will be helpful:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryState];
```

For detail, refer [THIS](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/device/display-battery-state-and-level-of-charge.html) link. It will elaborate you.